# Define where condition between specified interval in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want select between 1700300000 to 1700500000 also type of MemberID is nvarchar(50)

```
select * from tblmember
where cast(MenmberID as bigint) > 1700300000 and cast(MemberID as bigint) < 1700500000
```

> error: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 25
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: Looks good.  What is your problem?  What database are you using?

Comment: The title of this question does not really match your issue, which is a conversion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try_cast()`:

```
select *
from tblmember
where try_cast(MemberID as bigint) > 1700300000 and 
      try_cast(MemberID as bigint) < 1700500000
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but you might be able to use string comparisons:

```
select *
from tblmember
where MemberID > '1700300000' and 
      MemberID < '1700500000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have non-numerical data in the table. 
If the data is non-numerical, it fails the conversion.

In addition to Gordon's fine answers, you could try the following:

```
select * from tblmember
where 
(case when isnumeric(MemberID) = 1  then cast(MemberID as bigint) end) > 1700300000 and 
(case when isnumeric(MemberID) = 1  then cast(MemberID as bigint) end) < 1700500000
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tblmember
where case when isNumeric(MemberID) then cast(MenmberID as bigint)
else 0 end between  1700300000 and 1700500000;
```

something like that? (if you want/don't want the edge cases then you can play with the between -1/+1 on the values). What about 1700524234.3? Is that ok with you or does it have to be an integer?